# CUDA with one GPU on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, cuda

Is it possible to run CUDA with Tensorflow on Ubuntu with one GPU while in graphical desktop mode, or do you need at least one card for display?

Having to run in a text-only mode would be fine, but I was wondering if CUDA takes exclusive control of the GPU for its calculations, as my current work machine only has one capable PCIe slot.

Comment: [this](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x) may be of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - I'm doing this right now. A model runs on my gtx 1080 while still being in graphical desktop mode. As @robert crovella points out with his link:

> If no consideration is given to managing both sets of tasks
>   simultaneously, the system may experience disturbances and hangs in
>   the X Window system, leading to an interruption of processing
>   X-related tasks, such as display updates and rendering.

This has not happened to me yet. It is of course not easy for your tensorflow model to use the GPU on 100%. There is always some CPU calculations / variable handling inbetween.